# Updating Gemfile.lock fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I've updated a gem version in my `Gemfile`, so I'm trying to update `Gemfile.lock`. I run:

```
$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/......
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies.......
Fetching rake 10.5.0
Fetching i18n 0.8.1
Fetching minitest 5.7.0
Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
....
```

And get the following error despite it seems to be fetched already (see output above):

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/rake-10.5.0.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing rake (10.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

There's no such file under `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/`. The cache directory is writable (777).

If I run `gem install rake -v '10.5.0'` it works fine. But do I really need to install gems manually (error repeats for other packages)? I don't get such errors if just run `bundle install` without updating gems.

Comment: I'd suggest nuking the cache and trying again, something like `rm -r /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache`.

Comment: ok, so it seems I just understand the update command wrong, it assumes that the gems already installed

Comment: @chingis yes `bundle install` then `bundle update` if needed. Maybe answer your own question at some point in case another user stumbles across this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that setting write permissions on `cache` directory (`/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/cache/`) is not enough. You have to set write permissions for the parent directory (`/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/`). For some reason, `bundle update` doesn't write to `cache` unless you do that even though it doesn't write anything to any other directories on the same level as `cache`.

Comment: e.g. `chmod  -R 775 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/`

Comment: 775 might be not enough, in my case the directory owned by root. I just changed the ownership of this dir to my user.

Comment: yes, true, I'm used to using chruby where rubies are installed to my user account.